# I would like to integrate docusign with my application

Tags: docusignapi

I am using a sharepoint environment for maintaining documents. I would like to integrate docusign with my sharepoint environment as some document needs to be signed. Is there any possibilities for integrating these two ?. Any specific guidelines for API integration with sharepoint environment?. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Prasath.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free Connector that you can use to easily integrate **SharePoint 2010** with DocuSign (http://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-sharepoint-2010). If you're using another version of SharePoint, integration is still possible, but you'll likely have to build it yourself using the DocuSign API (and SharePoint API) to integrate the two systems.  The DocuSign Developer Center (http://www.docusign.com/developer-center) contains a wealth of information about using the DocuSign APIs.

Comment: Had a brief idea on this. Thanks @Kim